# Вопрос по assets rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Не пойму как правильно работать с assets. Юзаю гем **jQuery-File-Upload** и в `application.js` прописал

```
//= require jquery-fileupload/basic-plus
//= require jquery-fileupload/vendor/tmpl
```

Потом генерирую `rake assets:precompile` и сгенереный js получается 1.6Мб, что мне кажется очень много. Но вопрос в другом, эти библиотеки нужны только для одного экшена, для загрузки изображений. Но грузится этот огромный js на каждой странице сайта. Можно ли указывать конкретные библиотеки для конкретных контроллеров? Также coffee скрипты сгенереные для каждого контроллера, сохраняются в этот общий большой js файл. Получается coffee скрипты тоже грузятся на всех, не только своих, экшенах.

Comment: А что если эти скрипты вставлять в той же вьюхе, на которой форма?

Comment: Ну, вообще говоря эти 1.6 Мб должны закэшироваться, но по меньшей мере один раз они должны скачаться, так что это явный перебор. Но что туда напихано в таких количествах? О_о

Comment: сейчас только понял что js не был в сжатом виде. при сжатии получился 600кб. но все равно мне кажется это слишком много. В js ничего нет кроме //= require jquery-fileupload/basic-plus
//= require jquery-fileupload/vendor/tmpl

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой способ, который я нашел, это поместить в класс тега body (view/layout/aplication.html.erb), название контроллера и название экшена:

```
<body class="<%= controller_name %> <%= action_name %>">
```

После этого, можно будет ассинхронно вызывать необходимые для конкретного контроллера скрипты, например:

```
$('.имя-контроллера.имя-экшена').ready(function(){
// какой-нибудь код;
})

$('.products.index').ready(function(){
// какой-нибудь код;
})
```

НО, turbolinks не умеет работать с $(...).ready(function(){...}), поэтому для работы таких скриптов необходимо добавить гем gem 'jquery-turbolinks'. Или же можно обойтись без гема, добавив в assets js-скрипт из этого урока:  http://brandonhilkert.com/blog/page-specific-javascript-in-rails/ - там же можно и прочитать более подробно, как это все работает.

При данном методе обеспечивается ассинхронность, но все равно все собирается в одном файле. Для того. чтобы подгружать разные сборки для разных контроллеров, можно воспользоваться вот этим уроком:
http://theflyingdeveloper.com/controller-specific-assets-with-rails-4/

Однако, я бы посоветовал присмотреться к использованию webpack, он умеет делать все что Вам нужно. Вот неплохой урок, по замене стандартного сборщика rails на webpack: http://clarkdave.net/2015/01/how-to-use-webpack-with-rails/ .

Comment: спасибо за отличные ссылки